# JList with enter key

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` already having 3 elements.  Now what I want is if I press the enter key on that element i want to open a new `JList` with new list of create,alter,view as i mentioned below.. I have tried the below code:

```
Object l1=master.getSelectedValue();
int key = evt.getKeyCode();
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
         Object ind = master.getSelectedValue();
     //data.add(master.getSelectedValue());
     //master.setListData(data);
         DefaultListModel listmodel=new DefaultListModel();
         listmodel.addElement("Create");
         listmodel.addElement("View");
         listmodel.addElement("Alter");
           //  String[] data = {"Create","View","Alter"};
             JList list = new JList(listmodel);
              list.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: `.im need of urgent help..as in urgent..` == post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JList in local variable, especially if you are `im new here..`

Comment: *"im need of urgent help"*  Then you should have asked sooner.  Do you expect us to ignore the slew of people with questions and good time management skills, just to help you?

Comment: `I have a JList already with 3 elements. Now what I want is if I press the enter key on that element it will open a new JList.` == look at KeyBindings, register ENTER key for JList and focus in the window properly (nobody knows whats  `it will open a new JList.`)

Comment: Remember that users on this site here are helping voluntarily in their own free time. Telling us that it's urgent doesn't make us more sympathetic but rather adds more stress to the situation. We'll be more than willing to help when you have shown that you have taken the time to think about the problem, have done some research, and have posted a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) will help you. You create an Action and then the Action will be invoked when you use the Enter key or a mouse double click. When you design a GUI the user should be able to use either the mouse or the keyboard. This class makes it easy to do this.